# Appending <ol> with a <li> of <div> elements is causing an annoying bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

Here is the code I currently have.

```
if (playerCode.length === 4) {

    $("div.codeOption, #inGameInstructions").css("display", "none");
    for (i = 0; i < playerCode.length; i++) {
        if (playerCode[i] === "red") {
            $("#playersFinalCode").append("<li class= 'playerCodeChoice'>" + "<div style='background-color:#B30C15; width:20px; height:20px; border-radius:5px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;'>"
                "</div>" + "<br/>" + "</li>");
        } else if (playerCode[i] === "green") {
            $("#playersFinalCode").append("<li class= 'playerCodeChoice'>" + "<div style='background-color:#0D822C; width:20px; height:20px; border-radius:5px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;'>"
                "</div>" + "<br/>" + "</li>");
        } else if (playerCode[i] === "orange") {
            $("#playersFinalCode").append("<li class= 'playerCodeChoice'>" + "<div style='background-color:#E86E02; width:20px; height:20px; border-radius:5px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;'>"
                "</div>" + "<br/>" + "</li>");
        } else if (playerCode[i] === "yellow") {
            $("#playersFinalCode").append("<li class= 'playerCodeChoice'>" + "<div style='background-color:#F2E311; width:20px; height:20px; border-radius:5px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;'>"
                "</div>" + "<br/>" + "</li>");
        } else if (playerCode[i] === "blue") {
            $("#playersFinalCode").append("<li class= 'playerCodeChoice'>" + "<div style='background-color:#0D1782; width:20px; height:20px;border-radius:5px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;'>"
                "</div>" + "<br/>" + "</li>");
        } else {
            $("#playersFinalCode").append("<li class= 'playerCodeChoice'>" + "<div style='background-color:#570D82; width:20px; height:20px;border-radius:5px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;'>"
                "</div>" + "<br/>" + "</li>");
        }

        $(document).on("click", ".playerCodeChoice, #toMainMenu", function() {
            $(".playerCodeChoice").remove();
        });
    }
}
```

What this currently does is run through an array of colors, putting each element (a total of four) into an ordered list with a  element corresponding to the colors found in the array. This is what it's currently doing (for example).
These are really squares,

```
1. [yellow]

2. [orange]

3. [yellow]

4. [blue]
```

Now this is working for the most part, the list clears when I click on any of the colored squares as well as when I go back to the main menu but when I pick four new colors again the list doesn't start where it's suppose to. It moves downward and starts from where the last list left off nd each time I run through the process again it moves the list further and further down. Any ideas as to what could be causing this? Also bonus question. Eventually I'm going to want to display the four colors as one list, 10 times so something like,

```
1. [yellow], [orange], [yellow], [blue] 
2. etc.
3. etc.
etc.
```

If I wanted to do something like that would it be as simple as hooking it up so that multiple s are created (10) because eventually I'm going to want the computer to guess the player's color choices and then have those guesses displayed on screen. Hence why I'm playing around with this set up now. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Here is what I'm working on if you need the whole picture. 
http://codepen.io/terratunaz/pen/pbuyA

Comment: Is the code you posted inside another event handler? You shouldn't add another `click` handler every time the event occurs.

Comment: What happened to your codepen? It doesn't match the code in your question any more. It looks like a mix of my answer and your original code. You added the use of `class=playerCode[i]`, but you kept the `if` statements even though they're not needed.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing quite a bit last night. I kept the "if" statements because I only want those colors chosen by the player to be appended.

Comment: If you link a codepen to a question, you should fork it before editing, so that the link still works.

Comment: Here is a forked version.
http://codepen.io/terratunaz/pen/zxoZmM

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` isn't allowed inside `<li>`. So the browser is putting all the `<br>` tags outside the `<li>` elements. When you do `$(".playerCodeChoice").remove()` it removes all the `<li>`s, but the `<br>`s are left.

The solution is to remove `+ "<br/>"` from your JS.

BTW, all that repeated code in the `if/else` block is bothersome. Use CSS classes to assign the styles:

```
.playerCodeChoice div {
    width:20px; 
    height:20px; 
    border-radius:5px; 
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
}
.playerCodeChoice div.red {
    background-color: #B30C15;
}
.playerCodeChoice div.green {
    background-color: #0D822C
}
....


$("#playersFinalCode").append("<li class= 'playerCodeChoice'><div class='" + playerCode[i] + "'></div></li>");
```

Comment: *(c.)* *`<br>` isn't allowed inside `<li>`.* Per my information a `LI` element ***can*** contain any *flow content* element ([here's a list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1))

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact reason, but in the DOM the `<br>` ends up outside the `<li>`.

Comment: If you take a look at the OP's code you'll see he has a static `OL` element `#playerFinalCode` but at some point he appends a `P` element to it (created a jsBin for ease-code-read http://jsbin.com/topaci/1/edit?html,js,output see in line 32) (dbl click "JavaScript" to see line-numbers). For the other OP's requests I would really not get much into it cause it's pretty unclear and strange what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: I ended up changing the OL element to a DIV. I'll try to be clearer. So you, the player, picks a four color code out of a possible of six colors. After you choose your code the computer has to figure out what that code is and they only get 10 turns. I want to eventually make it so that each time the computer makes a guess, that guess is displayed on screen. So if it takes 3 guesses for the computer to make then there will be 3 codes on screen. So like 

1. [] [] [] []
2. [] [] [] []
3. [] [] [] []

Comment: I figured out how to do this, somewhat and got much further along than I was before. Thanks @Barmar and Roko for the help. :)